# How can I get the balance of tokens on ethereum address using blockcypher?

Tags: etherscan

How can I get the balance of tokens on ethereum address using [blockcypher](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/ethereum/#address-api)?

For example, I have an address on [cobinhood](https://cobinhood.com/), and there are my COB tokens.
When I look at the  to my address, I see only transactions, and nothing more (https://www.etherchain.org/account/a40cb6c128f668a36c933f74d8a5fb796985e00a), but how do I use this information to display the number of my tokens?

I want to create a dashboard in which I can see how many tokens I have on different addresses.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the balance of tokens on ethereum address using
>   blockcypher?

There is no such method in the blockcypher API.

A "token" is a contract that keeps a list of accounts that have balances. When you 'send a token' to some one you are really telling the contract to adjust your balance and credit another. Everything is stored in the contracts memory.